# Подскажите как вывести 3 "уровень" 3-х мерного массива?

Tags: php

Есть код

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT [name], [date], [status], row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS rownum
  FROM [script_monitoring].[dbo].[script_status]) [script_status] where rownum <= 10";

$params = array();
$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_query, $params, $options);

if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$data = array();
$data_names = array();
$n = 0;

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
    $data[$n][$row[3]][0] = $row[0];
    $data[$n][$row[3]][1] = date_format($row[1], "Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $data[$n][$row[3]][2] = $row[2];
    $data_names[$n] = $row[0];
    //$data = array(
    //    [$n] => array(
    //        [$row[3]] => array($row[0], date_format($row[1], "Y-m-d H:i:s"), $row[2]
    //         )
    //    )
    // );
    $n++;
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

$unique_script_names = array_unique($data_names);

echo "<ul  class=\"main_table\">";
foreach ($unique_script_names as $script_name) {

    echo "<li><table id=\"" . $script_name . "\"class=\"script_table\">";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th colspan=\"4\">" . $script_name . "<span class=\"close_table_button\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-close\"></span></span></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>имя</th>";
    echo "<th>дата</th>";
    echo "<th>статус</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    $n = 0;
    $n2 = 1;
    foreach ($data[$n] as $data_row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($data_row[$n2] as $value) {
            echo "td" . $value . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $n++;
        $n2++;
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Интересует последняя часть, как правильно вывести массив?

Comment: что значить вывести?

Comment: попонятнее напишите вопрос, какая последняя часть, что за массив, непонятно же ничего

Comment: напишите нам пожалуйста результат функции print_r($unique_script_names); // и всем все станет ясно

Comment: Array (  [0] => Awayalogs
    [10] => DeleteOldBackups
    [13] => Departments_backup_d
    [23] => Departments_backup_f 
    [27] => skgkacc_flag 
    [37] => VSS_Backup 
    [40] => WindowsPrintingParsing 
    )

Answer (score 0):

Массив трехмерный, а выводите его как двумерный.

```
echo "td" . $value . "</td>";
```

Вот в этом месте $value одномерный массив.

Comment: получается echo "td" . $value[0] . "</td>",echo "td" . $value[1] . "</td>",echo "td" . $value[2] . "</td>"?

Comment: или же нужен еще 1 foreach?

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        if ($data[$i][$i][0] === $script_name) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $data[$i][$i][0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data[$i][$i][1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data[$i][$i][2] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        } else {
            $i++;
        }
    }
```